# Set variable, calculate, repeat

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a range, set a value on another sheet with a value from the range, recalculate the sheet, set a new value from the range, recalculate, and repeat this through the entire range.

Cells A2:A31 contain different values. I need to loop through A2:A31 and use each value to set the value of cell H10 on Sheet2. I need to then recalculate the spreadsheet as Sheet2 performs calculations using cell H10.

After I recalculate the sheet, I need to use the next value in the range as the value for H10 and then recalculate. I need to do this through the loop.

A2 = 7.5, so set H10 = 7.5 and recalculate 
THEN 
A3 = 8.6, so set H10 = 8.6 and recalculate 
THEN 
repeat through A31.

I have a subroutine that takes the result of the calculation on Sheet2 and pastes it into Sheet1. These results appear in Column K on Sheet1 via vlookup and the values are pasted.

The subroutine works fine, but I can't get the outer loop to cycle through the range.

Here is the code I have:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NextLoan()

Dim lookup As Range
Dim lookupRange As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lookCell As Range
Set lookupRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31")
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K2:K31")
Set lookup = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H10")

For Each lookCell In lookupRange
    lookup.Value = lookupRange.Value
    Calculate

    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value2 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value
        Else
        End If
        Next cell

    Next lookCell


End Sub
```

Comment: OffTopic: Please revisit older thread of yours. You have asked several question before, and while some of them are answered, you haven't thought about upvoting/accepting answers given. It's simple courtesy to do so. You can take a look at the site's [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are unfamiliar with the concept.

Comment: `lookup.Value = lookCell.Value`

Comment: Your description doesn't mention Col K so it's difficult to see what the problem is exactly.  What is the inner loop [supposed to be] doing?

Comment: @TimWilliams Col K is used in the sub-routine that works without issue. I'll update the description.

Comment: @JvdV My apologies. I didn't know to do that. I will from now on.

Comment: But do you need to cycle though the entire ColK range for every cell in ColA, or just convert the one colK cell to a value?  Is the result of the calculations on Sheet2 a single value, or something else?

Comment: Your inner loop doesn't appear to serve much purpose. What am I missing? (Btw you can accept old answers as JvdV says.)

Comment: It would be useful to show the sub which populates ColK

Comment: Looks like it was a simple error that @NareshBhople caught. Thanks everyone.